# Send HTTP POST when the application is terminated

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, xcode6

I'm programming an application chat, and i want to log out when the user terminates the application from the background. For that I'm sending a request post to delete the user from the database. However The HTTP POST is not sending when i use it inside `applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application`

This is the whole code that i tried:

```
NSString *User_To_Be_Deleted = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"isLogin"];
NSMutableURLRequest *DeleteRequest  = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.8/Chatiw/Logout_Delete.php"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:30];



NSString *data_to_be_sent    = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"nickname=walidoss"];
[DeleteRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[DeleteRequest setHTTPBody:[data_to_be_sent dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];



NSURLConnection *myconnection  = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:DeleteRequest delegate:self];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"isLogin"];
```

The `NSURLCONNECTION` is not working when the app is terminated any suggestion or help please.

Comment: You are missing the startImediately after setting the delegate.

Comment: i did not understand you

Comment: Are the NSURLConnection delegate methods are getting called such as didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response

Comment: yes they are getting called

Comment: Is NSURLConnection gets called on main thread while coming back from background

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
NSURLConnection *myconnection  = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:DeleteRequest delegate:self];
```

for this:

```
NSURLConnection *myconnection  = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:DeleteRequest delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
```

**EDIT**

Try this code:

```
[[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    if(!error){
         //your code here on success
    } 
}] resume];
```

Comment: Getting the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and find out the solution.Do the following.

```
NSURLResponse* response = nil;
NSData *data = [data_to_be_sent dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:DeleteRequest returningResponse:&response error:nil];
```

Hope it works for you.